# Why do `SFINAE` (std::enable_if) uses bool literals instead of `true_t` / `false_t` tag classes?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I am trying to learn about `SFINAE` (i am following this [tutorial](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/sfinae-and-enable_if/#id5)), but there are some... "design choices" I do not understand and, as such, I find them confusing.

Let's assume I have a situation like this (included re-implementation of `std::enable_if` is there just to demonstrate how I understand `enable_if`)

```
// A default class (class type) declaration. Nothing unusual.
template <bool, typename T = void>
struct enable_if
{}; 

// A specialisation for <true, T> case. I understand 'why-s' of this. 
// -- 'why-s': if I attempt to access 'enable_if<false, T>::type' (which does not exist) I will get a substitution failure and compiler will just "move-on" trying to match "other cases".
template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T> {
    typedef T type;
};

// Here lies my problem:
template <class T,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,T>::type* = nullptr>
void do_stuff(T& t) { /* do stuff */ };
```

**(1)** The very 1st thing I have a "problem" with, is `bool` literal (`true`/`false`). I understand they are correct and templates can accept compile-time constant values of primitive data types (plain-old-data types) but if I were tasked to design the `enable_if` "mechanisms" instead of using `true`/`false` I would create a tag classes `true_t`(or `True`) and `false_t` (or `False`) as follows:

```
class true_t {}; // or True

class false_t {}; // or False

template<typename T>
class is_integral // just to have "something" to use with "enable_if"
{
    using result = false_t;
};

template<>
class is_integral<int32_t> // same with all other int types
{
    using result = true_t;
};

template <typename B, typename T = void>
struct enable_if
{}; 

template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true_t, T>
{
    using type = T;
};
```

**(2)** The second thing I find redundant is the need to specify `typename T` template parameter. Wouldn't it be easier / better to just implement `enable_if` as follows:

```
template <typename B>
struct enable_if
{}; 

template <>
struct enable_if<true_t>
{
    using type = void; // the 'type' exists therefore substitution failure will not occur. 
};
```

**I am well aware that all my propositions are extremely inferior to the currently existing solutions**, but I don't understand why... What portion of the functionality (important functionality) of current `SFINAE` did i shave off? (Not even realizing it...)

---

I know that, on this site, I am obligated to ask a single question within a... single "question-post-like" format, but if you find it acceptable could I also ask what will this syntax:

```
std::enable_if</* ... */>::type* = nullptr
```

accomplish? It's beyond my understanding right now...

Comment: `constexpr bool myCondition(...)`?

Comment: `template<std::size_t N> std::enable_if_t<N < 10> foo( char (&)[N]);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The very 1st thing I have a "problem" with, is `bool` literal (`true`/`false`). I understand they are correct and templates can accept compile-time constant values of primitive data types (plain-old-data types) but if I were tasked to design the `enable_if` "mechanisms" instead of using `true`/`false` I would create a tag classes `true_t`(or `True`) and `false_t` (or `False`) as follows

The issue with use a tag type instead of just a bool is that you have to add extra complexity to the code.  If you want to check a compile time condition, like `sizeof` for instance, you couldn't just do `sizeof(T) == 8`.  You would have to make an abstraction that does the check and the returns the appropriate tag type.

> The second thing I find redundant is the need to specify `typename T` template parameter. Wouldn't it be easier / better to just implement `enable_if` as follows

Not really.  What if you want to use the SFINAE for the return type?  You would only be able to have a void function then, which is unnecessarily limiting.  Instead what you can do is use what was later added in C++14 and C++17 and make  aliases. This makes the names non dependent and lets you drop the `typename`

```
template< bool B, class T = void >
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<B,T>::type;
template< class T >
inline constexpr bool is_integral_v = is_integral<T>::value;
```

This allows you to rewrite

```
template <class T,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,T>::type* = nullptr>
void do_stuff(T& t) { /* do stuff */ };
```

to

```
template <class T,
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>,T>* = nullptr>
void do_stuff(T& t) { /* do stuff */ };
```

although I prefer to use a bool for the type of `enable_if_t` like

```
template <class T,
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, bool> = true>
void do_stuff(T& t) { /* do stuff */ };
```

> I know that, on this site, I am obligated to ask a single question within a... single "question-post-like" format, but if you find it acceptable could I also ask what will this syntax:
>
> ```
> std::enable_if</* ... */>::type* = nullptr
> ```
>
> accomplish?

It makes a pointer to the type that `std::enable_if` "returns" and sets it to null pointer.  The goal here is to make a template parameter that will only exist if the condition is true.  You could rewrite it to

```
typename = typename std::enable_if</* ... */>::type
```

so instead of having a non type parameter you have a type parameter.  They both accomplish the same thing but the latter wont work with overloading the function for different `enable_if`'s since default template parameters are not part of the signature.  The first version which uses non type parameters is included in the function signature and does allow you to overload the `enable_if`'s.

Comment: The default value of a template parameter is not part of the signature, so using your last example will give an ambiguous error if you have function templates with "competing" SFINAE.

Comment: @super Good point.  I haven't used it so long I forgot why.  I've added that into the answer.

Comment: Now I understand what I did miss. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First off there exists tag-types for `true` and `false`, namely `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`.

Let's say we made the `enable_if` work with this instead of a bool parameter. You could then no longer do things like `std::enable_if<1 == 1>::type` since `1 == 1` evaluates to a bool. So does most things you will want to test here.

On the other hand, the existing tag types can be used in a `enable_if` since they contain a `value` and have a `operator()` that return said value.

So it seems to me that a lot of convenience would be lost in doing it your way, and from what I can see nothing would be gained.

For point 2, it's simply a convenience to be able to specify what type you want `enable_if` to hold if it's true. It defaults to `void`, but if you want you can easily have it deduce an `int`, `double` ect. which can be useful sometimes.