# std::enable_if_t: The best usage as function template parameter

Tags: c++, c++14

In the last days I read a lot of how to use enable_if_t correctly. There are a lot of different ways to use it. I want to use it for a function template parameter. I want to have the ability to overload the function. So according to cppreference.com the preferred way is to do it in this way:

```
template<typename Signed, std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<Signed>::value, bool> = true>
```

or

```
template<typename Signed, std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<Signed>::value, int> = 0>
```

There is no difference which type is used for std::enable_if_t. Seems to me it's a matter of taste. This is only interesting for function arguments, since almost nothing can be converted to void**. So for function arguments void** is the preferred way.

But I also tested lot of other suggestions:

```
template<typename Signed, std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<Signed>::value, Signed>* = nullptr>

template <typename Integer, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>* = nullptr>
```

Everything is working in my example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Signed,
             //std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<Signed>::value, bool> = true>
             //std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<Signed>::value, int> = 0>
             //std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<Signed>::value, void**> = nullptr>
             //std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<Signed>::value, Signed>* = nullptr>
             //std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<Signed>::value>* = nullptr>
             void printValue(Signed Value) {
                 std::cout << "Signed: " << Value << std::endl;
             }

template<typename Unsigned,
             //std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<Unsigned>::value, bool> = true>
             //std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<Unsigned>::value, int> = 0>
             //std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<Unsigned>::value, void**> = nullptr>
             //std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<Unsigned>::value, Unsigned>* = nullptr>
             //std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<Unsigned>::value>* = nullptr>
             void printValue(Unsigned Value) {
                 std::cout << "Unsigned: " << Value << std::endl;
             }


int main(){
    printValue(10);
    printValue(10u);
    return 0;
}
```

According to another post [Why do `SFINAE` (std::enable_if) uses bool literals instead of `true_t` / `false_t` tag classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852645/why-do-sfinae-stdenable-if-uses-bool-literals-instead-of-true-t-false)

```
template <typename Integer, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>* = nullptr>
```

should not work for overloaded functions. But it's working. Tested it also with Clang and GCC in different versions.

Could someone explain why it's working and what is the best way to do it, please. Or is there no difference in the end and everything is the same?

Comment: It is all working exactly the same. These days (post-2020) one should prefer `requires` over `enable_if` hackery anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I must use C++14 at work. So concepts are not avialable.